# How to Format ouput file using awk

Tags: shell, awk

I have the below output file in the below format from a shell script

```
data  text1

data1 text2

data3 text4,text5,text6,text7,text8,text9,text10,text12,text11,text13

data4 text53

data23 text45,text65,text98,text65`
```

Want to  change the format of the output further like below to be more readable

```
data   text1

data1  text2

data3  text4

data3  text5

data3  text6

data3  text7

data3  text8

data3  text9

data3  text10

data4  text53

data23 text45

data23 text65

data23 text98

data23 text65
```

please advise how to achieve the same using awk/sed ?
tried looking up for awk commands but not getting any clue as such  , any help would be appreciated 
Thanks

Comment: Do you **really** have a blank line between each input line and want the same in your output?

Comment: hello @ed i don't really need the blank line in between the ouput , but will be good to have  to make it more readable given it will have large number of records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk -F'[ ,]+' '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) print $1, $i ORS}' file
data text1

data1 text2

data3 text4

data3 text5

data3 text6

data3 text7

data3 text8

data3 text9

data3 text10

data3 text12

data3 text11

data3 text13

data4 text53

data23 text45

data23 text65

data23 text98

data23 text65
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
output | gawk '{split($2, a, /,/); for (i=1; i <= length(a); i++) {printf "%s %s\n\n", $1, a[i]}}'
```

Where `output` is the output generated by your script.

Alternatively, you run it like this:

```
gawk '{split($2, a, /,/); for (i=1; i <= length(a); i++) {printf "%s %s\n\n", $1, a[i]}}' output_file
```

Edited to fix errors pointed by @Ed Morton and replaced `awk` with `gawk` since `length(array)` is a GNU extension.

Comment: thanks @accdias .. 
i was looking up the man page  still trying to understand how '$2' will be assgined for the below line

`data3 text4,text5,text6,text7,text8,text9,text10,text12,text11,text13`

given after the FS "," the line will be split into a new line

Comment: ```$1 == "data3"``` and ```$2 == "text4,text5,text6,text7,text8,text9,text10,text12,text11,text13"```. Then ```split($2, a, ",")``` will fill array ```a``` with every value of $2 split at comma.

Comment: Any of your comments make any difference in this case.

Comment: And you are 12 hours and a half late.

Comment: Done is better than perfect and you are late either way.

Comment: Take it easy, @Ed Morton. I do accept constructive critics and that's why I went there and changed the code. Feel free to comment it if you want.

Comment: Alright. I see the error. Arrays in (g)awk are indexed starting at 1 and not 0.

Comment: No worries and I apologize for my bad behavior. Your comments are more than welcome, @Ed Morton.

Answer (score 0):

Another using `gsub` to `,`:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/,/, ORS ORS $1 OFS )}1' file
...
data3 text4

data3 text5

data3 text6
...
```

However, if `$1` has, for example, `&` in it, there will be trouble as it gets replaced with the match:

```
$ cat file
data& text4,text5,text6
$ awk '{gsub(/,/, ORS ORS $1 OFS )}1' file
data& text4

data, text5

data, text6
```

Fix that with another `gsub`:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/,/, ORS ORS $1 OFS ); gsub(/,/,"\\&")}1' file
data& text4

data& text5

data& text6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fold a line one time with

```
sed -r 's/([^ ]* +)([^,]*),(.*)/\1\2\n\n\1\3/g' file
```

Repeating it needs a marker a jump

```
sed -r ': a;s/([^ ]* +)([^,]*),(.*)/\1\2\n\n\1\3/g; t a' file
```