# Use awk to match & store, append the pattern and also split the line having a delimiter

Tags: awk

I am having the below output from a text file which I need to format to be more readable.

```
julian text:case2345
maria  text:case4567
clover text,text,text,text,text,text:case3456
neil   text,text:case09876
```

I need to reformat the output as follows:

```
julian text:case2345
maria  text:case4567
clover text:case3456 
clover text:case3456
clover text:case3456
clover text:case3456
clover text:case3456
clover text:case3456
neil   text:case09876
neil   text:case09876
```

Using `awk` I was trying to match the pattern case[0-9], store it in a variable and then split the line using delimiter "," and finally print.
I was trying below earlier but couldn't get the desired output

```
awk '/match($0,/case[0-9]/){val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);next}{split($2,k,","); for (i in k) {printf ("%s %s %s\n\n",$1,k[i],val)}}'
```

Comment: its a typo , just reviewed the actual input file and there is no space in between 'case' and the numbers ..thanks for noticing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following `awk` may help here. (Considering that your actual Input_file is the shown sample).

```
awk -F' +|,|:' '$NF~/[cC][aA][sS][eE]/ && NF>2{for(i=2;i<=(NF-1);i++){print $1 OFS $i":"$NF};next} 1' Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk -F' +|,|:' '
$NF~/[cC][aA][sS][eE]/ && NF>2{
  for(i=2;i<=(NF-1);i++){
    print $1 OFS $i":"$NF};
  next
}
1
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for code now too.

```
awk -F' +|,|:' '           ##Setting field separator as space(s) OR comma OR colon here for each line.
$NF~/[cCaAsSeE]/ && NF>2{  ##Checking condition here if last field is having case OR CASE string in it and number of fields are more than 2.
  for(i=2;i<=(NF-1);i++){  ##Starting a for loop which starts from 2nd value to second last value of total fields value here.
    print $1 OFS $i":"$NF};##first field OFS(whose default value is space) value of current field and colon with last field of line.
  next                     ##next is awk default keyword which will skip all further lines now.
}
1                          ##Only those lines will come here which was NOT true for above conditions, simple printing of line will happen here.
' Input_file               ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: @thanks Ravinder for the explanation..really helps ,  am working on the same will confirm  , is --> awk -F ' +|   setting field separator for spaces ? what is the significance of '+'

Comment: @shirop, `+` means take more than 1 continuous  occurrence of spaces together(as a single field)

Comment: `$NF~/[cCaAsSeE]/` in your final script is not the same as `$NF~/[cC][aA][sS][eE]/` in your first 2 versions but in any case consider just calling tolower instead of creating upper and lower case character lists within bracket expression for every char in a regexp, e.g. use `tolower($NF) ~ /case/` instead of `$NF~/[cC][aA][sS][eE]/`. Also, `i<=(NF-1)` is the same as `i<NF` and you don't need the semi-colons at the end of lines. Finally - the `next` statement and `1` are doing nothing given the OPs posted sample input.

Answer (score 2):

Just tweak [the answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50658106/1745001):

```
$ awk -F'[ ,:]+' '{for (i=2;i<NF;i++) print $1, $i ":" $NF}' file
julian text:case2345
maria text:case4567
clover text:case3456
clover text:case3456
clover text:case3456
clover text:case3456
clover text:case3456
clover text:case3456
neil text:case09876
neil text:case09876
```

Comment: how is the split happening here in the for loop, given we are not explicitly mentioning which delimiter to use in split ..say  like  ..split($2,arr,/,/)  @thanks

Comment: You don't need a separate, explicit call to split() since awk already splits each record into fields based on the value of FS which I'm setting with `-F'[ ,:]+'` so awk splits the input every time it sees spaces, commas, or colons.

Answer (score 1):

```
# set field separator
awk -F '[: ]+' '/,/{                                # if line/row/record contains comma 
                    split($2,arr,/,/);              # split 2nd field by comma, 
                                                    # store elements in array arr
                    for(i=1; i in arr;i++)          # iterate through array arr
                         print $1, arr[i] ":" $NF;  # print 1st field, array element and last field from record
                    next                            # stop processing go to next line
                                                    # 1 at the end does default operation that is print $0
                }1' infile
```

Test Results:

```
$ cat infile
julian text:case2345
maria  text:case 4567
clover text,text,text,text,text,text:case3456
neil   text,text:case09876

$ awk -F '[: ]+' '/,/{split($2,arr,/,/);for(i=1; i in arr;i++)print $1,arr[i]":"$NF;next}1' infile
julian text:case2345
maria  text:case 4567
clover text:case3456
clover text:case3456
clover text:case3456
clover text:case3456
clover text:case3456
clover text:case3456
neil text:case09876
neil text:case09876
```

Comment: thanks @Akshay ..can you please explain what is this  -->  '[: ]+'

and also is  $NF storing the last value of the field ? and how the value is getting assigned in $NF ?

Comment: found the gnu-manual which explain $NF will always represent the last field

[link](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Fields.html)